# Object with time in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have this

```
$.each(data, function (id, item) {
                    var tempDate = new Date();
                    var tempTime = item.Time;
                    debugger;
                    tempDate =new Date(parseInt(item.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                    self.items.push({ Name: item.Name, Date: (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + tempDate .getDate() + '/' + tempDate.getFullYear(), Time: tempTime });
                });
```

The main proble how to get time from tempTime it has type Object and function getHours do not work.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. `tempTime` has an `Hours` property, so instead of `getHours()`, you can just do `tempTime.Hours`. Or are you asking how turn `tempTime` into a `Date` object? Some more clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Initialising *tempDate* with a date instance is pointless since that value is immediately overwritten with another.

Comment: @McMath, You are right write answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the hours from `tempTime`, all you have to do is access the value of the `Hours` property, like so:

```
tempTime.Hours // => 11
```